# Unable to insert rows in database using Spring Batch + Spring data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

I am working with legacy database in which db tables has no keys. For java Sake i have to used Id annotation. My goal is to read data from .dat file and insert it into table. I'm using spring batch for the above said purpose. To improve the performance threading is used. But i'm getting insertion/updation issue that i'm unable to figure out. I have referenced many sources but none seems to solve my purpose. Kindly help me out by giving some appropriate solution or reference. Thanks in advance...

Entity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "int_repl_mkt_val")
public class IntReplMktVal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private IntReplMktValId id;

    @Column(name = "acct_sys_cd")
    private String acctSysCd;

    @Column(name = "co_num", nullable = false)
    private Integer coNum;

    @Column(name = "last_mod_tmstmp")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModTmstmp;

    @Column(name = "pim_owned", nullable = false)
    private String pimOwned;

    @Column(name = "position", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal position;

    @Column(name = "pricing_plan")
    private String pricingPlan;

    @Column(name="source_system",nullable=false)
    private String sourceSystem;

    ... getter and setter

}
```

EmbeddedClass.java

```
@Embeddable
public class IntReplMktValId implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4824041485763129937L;

    @Column(name = "acct_id",nullable=false)
    private Integer acctId;

    @Column(name = "asset_id",nullable=false)
    private Integer assetId;

    ... getter and setter
}
```

jpaRepository.class

```
@Repository
public interface IntReplMktValRepository extends JpaRepository<IntReplMktVal, IntReplMktValId> 
{

}
```

BatchConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
public class IMAPPositionBatchConfiguration 
{
    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @StepScope
    @Bean(name="imapPositionReader")
    public FlatFileItemReader<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) throws IOException 
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO> newBean = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        newBean.setName("fileReader");
        newBean.setResource(new InputStreamResource(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(fileName))));
        newBean.setLineMapper(this.lineMapper());
        newBean.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return newBean;
    }

    public DefaultLineMapper<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO> lineMapper() 
    {
        DefaultLineMapper<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(this.lineTokenizer());
        IMAPPositionReader imapPositionReader = new IMAPPositionReader();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(imapPositionReader);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer() 
    {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        tokenizer.setNames("field1","field2","field3");
        tokenizer.setIncludedFields(5,4,7);
        return tokenizer;
    }

    public ItemProcessor<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO, IntReplMktVal> processor() 
    {
        return new IMAPPositionProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name="imapPositionBatchWriter")
    public ItemWriter<IntReplMktVal> writer() 
    {
        return new IMAPPositionWriter();
    }

    @Bean(name="imapPositionListener")
    public JobExecutionListenerSupport jobCompletionListener()
    {
        return new IMAPPositionJobListener();
    }

    @Bean(name="imapPositionTaskExecutor")    
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() 
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean(name="imapPositionStep")
    public Step step(@Autowired @Qualifier("imapPositionTaskExecutor")TaskExecutor taskExecutor) throws IOException 
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("imapPositionStep")
                .<IMAPPositionInputMapperDTO, IntReplMktVal>chunk(100)
                .reader(this.reader(null))
                .processor(this.processor())
                .writer(this.writer())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name="imapPositionFileImportJob")
    public Job importUserJob(@Autowired @Qualifier("imapPositionStep") Step step) 
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("imapPositionFileImportJob"+new Date())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(this.jobCompletionListener())
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

BatchWriter.java

```
public class IMAPPositionWriter implements ItemWriter<IntReplMktVal>
{
    @Autowired
    IntReplMktValRepository intReplMktValRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends IntReplMktVal> items) throws Exception 
    {
        intReplMktValRepository.saveAll(items);     
    }

}
```

ErrorLog

```
2019-06-07 17:22:01,522 ERROR [scopedTarget.imapPositionTaskExecutor-4] org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Duplicate identifier in table for: [com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.entities.IntReplMktVal#component[acctId,assetId]{assetId=274800, acctId=1}]]
```

NOTE: I have to insert all the data into table regardless of duplication or any other issue as keys are not defined so every data is valid.

Comment: Can you alter the target table?

Comment: Yes, I can execute DML Commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was due to duplication found in persistent context which was resolved by setting the chunk size to 1.